# How do you display a PDF file form the local directory on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, pdf, uiwebview

How do you display a PDF file form the local directory on an iPad?

Loading it into a WebView shows up blank?

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"display" ofType:@"pdf"];      
NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfURL];
[self.webDisplay loadRequest:request];
```

Where "self.webDisplay" is a UIWebView.  The PDF doesn't show up, just a blank webview.